# Framework for net core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I’m a beginner in C#. I’m learning Net Core MVC. In all tutorials, used Entity Framework and Microsoft's DB for implementation of the Model. However, I have Oracle database, as I understand it for net core there is no implementation. Tell me that you can use me instead of EF or maybe I missed something.

Comment: [This document suggests differently](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/tech-info/odpnet-dotnet-ef-core-sod-4395108.pdf) - are you sure there's no .NET Core implementation? It also seems that you can indirectly use Oracle through ADO if you're right that there isn't a .NET Core implementation.

Comment: Look [what I have found](https://entityframeworkcore.com/providers-oracle) for just 0.31 seconds of googling _"ef core oracle"_! It's an Oracle Entity Framework Core tutorial! Next time, just try to search a little.

Comment: @vasily.sib 
I think this information is outdated and not at all relevant.

Comment: @ИльясБалгабеков why do you think so? Anyway, the key point of my comment was _"just try to search a little"_. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/) is a second link from _"ef core oracle"_ google search. And (just to be sure you find it) [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/latest-news/index.html) is a link to Oracle page with instructions on how to setup your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore/

there is information on the developer portal for its usage.  I haven't used oracle since .net 1.0 but there is core support and its been some time coming.

And for good measure https://community.oracle.com/community/groundbreakers/database/developer-tools/windows_and_.net/odp.net